# Deploying EmberJS to AWS using SSH + RSync

Tags: ember.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ember-cli

I've managed to deploy a simple todo app unto AWS with S3 using this site
http://emberigniter.com/deploy-ember-cli-app-amazon-s3-linux-ssh-rsync/

However, when I attempt to do this ( Deploying with SSH and Rsync ) according to the tutorial, I run into the following error:

- gzipping `**/*.{js,css,json,ico,map,xml,txt,svg,eot,ttf,woff,woff2}`
- ignoring `null`
- ✔  assets/ember-user-app-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css
- ✔  assets/vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css
- ✔  assets/ember-user-app-45a9825ab0116a8007bb48645b09f060.js
- ✔  crossdomain.xml
- ✔  robots.txt
- ✔  assets/vendor-d008595752c8e859a04200ceb9a77874.js
- gzipped 6 files ok
  |
  +- upload
  |  |
  |  +- rsync

### - Uploading using rsync...

**- Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).**

**rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]**

**rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]**

The following is my config/deploy.js

```
module.exports = function(deployTarget) {
    var ENV = {
        build: {
        environment: deployTarget
    },

    's3-index': {
        accessKeyId: "<myKeyID>",
        secretAccessKey: "<mySecret>",
        bucket: "emberjsft",
        region: "ap-southeast-1",
        allowOverwrite: true
    },
    's3': {
        accessKeyId: "<myKeyID>",
        secretAccessKey: "<mySecret>",
        bucket: "emberjsft",
        region: "ap-southeast-1"
    },

    'ssh-index': {
        remoteDir: "/var/www/",
        username: "ec2-user",
        host: "ec2-<elastic-ip>.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
        privateKeyFile: "/Users/imac/MY_AWS_PEMFILE.pem", 
        allowOverwrite: true
    },
    rsync: {
        dest: "/var/www/",
        username: "ec2-user",
        host: "ec2-<elastic-ip>.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
        delete: false
    }
    // include other plugin configuration that applies to all deploy targets here
    };

    if (deployTarget === 'development') {
        ENV.build.environment = 'development';
    // configure other plugins for development deploy target here
    }

    if (deployTarget === 'staging') {
        ENV.build.environment = 'production';
    // configure other plugins for staging deploy target here
    }

    if (deployTarget === 'production') {
        ENV.build.environment = 'production';
    // configure other plugins for production deploy target here
    }

    // Note: if you need to build some configuration asynchronously, you can return
    // a promise that resolves with the ENV object instead of returning the
    // ENV object synchronously.
    return ENV;
};
```

How should I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent the last hour fighting the same issue as you. I was able to *kind of* fix it by using `ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/example-key.pem` and removing `privateKeyFile`.

I still get a error thrown after the transfer ends, but can confirm all files successfully transferred to my EC2 box despite the error..

**deploy.js**

```
module.exports = function (deployTarget) {

  var ENV = {
    build: {
      environment: deployTarget
    },
    'ssh-index': {
      remoteDir: "/var/www/",
      username: "ubuntu",
      host: "52.xx.xx.xx",
      allowOverwrite: true
    },
    rsync: {
      host: "ubuntu@52.xx.xx.xx",
      dest: "/var/www/",
      recursive: true,
      delete: true
    }
  };

  return ENV;

};
```

Comment: Awesome, gonna give it a try with this, I'll just upvote it since it looks entirely feasible and plausible

Answer (score -1):

In your deploy.js file you need to place your information for accessKeyId.  You left "" in the place of accessKeyId.  You need to put your information there.  Same for secretAccessKey, acessKeyId, plus your host , you need to put your elastic-ip address.

Comment: In the real file, I've included the actual necessary information, only in here, do I omit putting in real data.

Answer (score -2):

`myKeyID` and `mySecret` shall be present in a `.env` file and then accessed here by `process.env.myKeyID` , `process.env.mySecret`

Not a good practice to hard-code the Keys in `deploy.js` file.
Best practise would be read it using [Consul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consul)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how putting it in an external file helps to resolve the issue which is more important than say maintainability at the moment.